# Unable to call DOC_INFO_BY_NAME from a Custom WCC Java Service

Tags: java, java-6, oracle-ucm

I'm creating a Custom Java Component for [oracle-ucm](/questions/tagged/oracle-ucm) to do some processing based on passed in Excel Files.  The files are keyed off of *Content ID*.
one of the first things the application does after reading the excel file is call **DOC_INFO_BY_NAME**.

**In short**:  Why can't **DOC_INFO_BY_NAME** by name find `dProcessingState` and how do I fix it?

**Full Details Below**

---

However, when I do I get the following Error Message:

**Error getting DOC_INFO for 'LOCALHOST16200000001'. Unable to retrieve information for 'LOCALHOST16200000001'. Unable to retrieve file format information. Cannot find the parameter 'dProcessingState'. [ Details ]**

An error has occurred. The stack trace below shows more information.

```
!$Error getting DOC_INFO for 'LOCALHOST16200000001'.!csUnableToGetRevInfo2,LOCALHOST16200000001!csUnableToGetFileFormatInfo!syParameterNotFound,dProcessingState
intradoc.common.ServiceException: !csUnableToGetRevInfo2,LOCALHOST16200000001!csUnableToGetFileFormatInfo
        at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.buildServiceException(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:2176)
        at intradoc.server.Service.buildServiceException(Service.java:2404)
        at intradoc.server.Service.createServiceExceptionEx(Service.java:2398)
        at intradoc.server.Service.createServiceException(Service.java:2393)
        at intradoc.server.DocCommonHandler.getDocFormats(DocCommonHandler.java:271)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at intradoc.common.IdcMethodHolder.invokeMethod(IdcMethodHolder.java:86)
        at intradoc.common.ClassHelperUtils.executeMethodReportStatus(ClassHelperUtils.java:324)
        at intradoc.server.ServiceHandler.executeAction(ServiceHandler.java:79)
        at intradoc.server.Service.doCodeEx(Service.java:622)
        at intradoc.server.Service.doCode(Service.java:594)
        at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.doAction(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1693)
        at intradoc.server.Service.doAction(Service.java:566)
        at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.doActions(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1483)
        at intradoc.server.Service.doActions(Service.java:561)
        at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.executeActions(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1415)
        at intradoc.server.Service.executeActions(Service.java:547)
        at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.doRequestInternalEx(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:958)
        at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.executeServiceTopLevelSimple(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1070)
        at com.lowes.content.edam.massMetaDataUpdate.service.types.ServicesWrapper.executeService(ServicesWrapper.java:139)
        at com.lowes.content.edam.massMetaDataUpdate.service.file.GetFileService.getDocInfo(GetFileService.java:478)
        at com.lowes.content.edam.massMetaDataUpdate.service.ServiceFieldMapper.getMappings(ServiceFieldMapper.java:76)
        at com.lowes.content.edam.massMetaDataUpdate.file.mapper.impl.FieldMapWorker.doInBackground(FieldMapWorker.java:107)
        at com.lowes.content.edam.massMetaDataUpdate.file.mapper.impl.FieldMapWorker.doInBackground(FieldMapWorker.java:37)
        at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:277)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: intradoc.data.DataException: !syParameterNotFound,dProcessingState
        at intradoc.data.DataBinder.getEx(DataBinder.java:1258)
        at intradoc.data.DataBinder.get(DataBinder.java:1057)
        at intradoc.server.DocCommonHandler.getProcessingState(DocCommonHandler.java:277)
        at intradoc.server.DocCommonHandler.getDocFormats(DocCommonHandler.java:184)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at intradoc.common.IdcMethodHolder.invokeMethod(IdcMethodHolder.java:87)
        at intradoc.common.ClassHelperUtils.executeMethodReportStatus(ClassHelperUtils.java:324)
        at intradoc.server.ServiceHandler.executeAction(ServiceHandler.java:79)
        at intradoc.server.Service.doCodeEx(Service.java:622)
        at intradoc.server.Service.doCode(Service.java:595)
        ... 20 more
```

I've tried multiple ways of calling the additional service.
currently I'm using:

```
public DataBinder executeService(DataBinder binder, Workspace workspace) 
       throws DataException, ServiceException 
{  
  final String serviceName = binder.getLocal(Services.IdcService);

  //check for REMOTE_USER
  String username = binder.getEnvironmentValue("REMOTE_USER");

  if ( null == username || "".equals(username.trim()))         
  {
     log.warn("username not found, searching the binder.");
     try { username = binder.get("dUser"); }
     catch (DataException de) { log.error("Unable to get Username.", de); }
     if ( null != username && !"".equals(username.trim()))            
     { binder.setEnvironmentValue("REMOTE_USER", username); }
     else { throw new IllegalStateException("Username required!"); }
  }

  //clear idcToken
  binder.getLocalData().remove("idcToken");

  log.info("About to run '" + serviceName + "' as '" + username +"'");

  try 
  {
     log.info("Calling service " + serviceName + ": " 
             + binder.getLocalData().toString());
     // Execute service
     service.createRequestImplementor();
     service.getRequestImplementor()
            .executeServiceTopLevelSimple(binder, serviceName, 
                                          service.getUserData());
     log.info("Finished calling service");
     return service.getBinder();
  } 
  catch (DataException e) 
  {
     String msg = "Unexpected Failure executing service '"+serviceName+"'";
     log.info(msg, e);
     throw e; //log and duck
  }
}
```

So why can't WCC find `dProcessingState`, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way of calling the service is fairly standard and I don't think that is the reason. My first guess is that your other code is interfering with your call to DOC_INFO_BY_NAME. If you disable all your other custom code (perhaps easier said than done) and call the service in a clean component, then I think it'll work. Second candidate is to reconsider if your custom service really should be a FileService. Not sure if that affects the result, but perhaps worth a try.

Comment: I'm not using `Intradoc.server.FileService`.  The `GetFileService` classname is historical.  It's from a *CIS / RIDC* version of the app that bundled **GET_FILE** and **DOC_INFO** functions into a single class

Answer (score 0):

It almost seems like a bug to me.

*getProcessingState()* is called from *getDocFormats()* which is called from the DOC_INFO* service.

The code for getProcessingState() first retrieves *dProcessingState*.

```
 String curProcState = this.m_binder.get("dProcessingState");
```

Then, it checks if this is null:

```
if (curProcState != null)
```

However, it never gets to the null check. This is because *DataBinder.get()* is requiring a value for any key passed in (in this case *dProcessingState*.)

Trying setting *dProcessingState* to a value in the DataBinder before calling the service.

```
binder.setLocal("dProcessingState", "ignore");
```

Comment: Adding that to the binder just lead to a different error with something else missing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was totally my fault. I had tried to be fancy, and extend `Databinder` to make it easier for me to use. Turns out my extension was faulty.
Rolling back to the default and double checking my data in the binder fixed it.